# Text mining - word frequency from a single column containing list

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, word-frequency

Here is my dataset:

https://app.box.com/s/yotsy58ud2k9yk7vs7sj8ksc0favhevv

I'm trying to create a frequency table of the tags from a single column with following structure:

[image]

I tried using `qdap` for simplicity, but the result is not correct

```
library(qdap)
tags_df <- read.csv(file.choose())
freq_terms(tags_df$tags)
```

**Solution**

Just improving (creating a data frame and sorting) the solution given by Rui:

```
sp <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(unlist(tags_df$tags)),'^c\\(|,|"|\\)'))

inx <- sapply(sp, function(y) nchar(trimws(y)) > 0 & !is.na(y))

data <- as_data_frame(table(tolower(sp[inx])))

data <- data[with(data,order(-n)),]

data <- data[1:10,]
```

Comment: you can used `table` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want or need is a frequency count, you can do without external packages, base R has a function `table`.

```
sp <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(unlist(tags_df$tags)), '^c\\(|,|"|\\)'))
inx <- sapply(sp, function(y) nchar(trimws(y)) > 0 & !is.na(y))
table(sp[inx])
#    Android        CSS3      Design      Hiring  JavaScript      NextJS 
#          1           1           1           1           4           1 
#     NodeJS programming Programming     ReactJS     Testing          UI 
#          1           1           3           3           1           1 
#         UX   WebDesign      webdev      WebDev 
#          1           2           1           4
```

**EDIT.**

I have just realized that you have `"programming"` and `"Programming"`, `"webdev"` and `"WebDev"` as tags, maybe you want to do a case-insensitive count. If this is the case, try instead

```
table(tolower(sp[inx]))
```

Comment: Figured out data. Updated the original post

Comment: @user709413 To sort the resultuse, well, `sort`. See the help page `help("sort")`.